# Distance Travel - QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance

I have the number of travels from one city to nearby cities.
I already created centroids for all of these cities.

And I want to create a map connecting this cities (by lines) and to give those line weight according to number of travels.

How do I create this lines? How do I make the connection between different cities - Table of attributtes?

In summary, I want to end up with something like this map:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you download the FlowMapper plugin for QGIS in order to achieve this. You will need to manipulate the data a little as the plugin accepts 3 .txt files:

1. Contains your node coordinates (your Centroid Coordinates).
2. Your node names (your Centroid Names).
3. A flow matrix containing your number of travels to each centroid.

From this you easily have the ability to add weighted symbology to each path.

This webpage gives a very good guide on how to achieve what you want:

https://gogeomatics.ca/mapping-migration-flows-with-qgis-flowmapper-plugin/

Answer (score -2):

Actually, i had no experience in QGIS. But it is possible to do this on ArcGIS using a route analysis model. This is a link if it helps. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-6-creating-a-model-for-route-analysis.htm.
This is going to be done using your road network and location data in your case centroids. But first, you should change your road data into a road data network dataset. which will be an input for the route layers. If you want to preserve distance and time you should also provide time, speed and distance information a within the road attribute tables. but if you just want to show the road networks the model will help.

Thanks,
Tamene

Comment: While your answer may be the correct way to do this in ArcGIS, this does not provide an answer for the OP since OPis asking for a solution in QGIS **not** in ArcGIS